# Ubuntu Web Server is not Accessible outside Localhost

Tags: apache2, wordpress

I have a web server running the latest version of Ubuntu, LAMP stack and everything else required to run a local server.
I managed to install wordpress on localhost/wordpress.
And going to just localhost brings up "This is a test page...."
When I type in the IP of the ubuntu running system on another network, i get the "This is a test page..." properly as it should come, however, when I go to myip/wordpress it says that a PHP file is missing in /etc/wordpress/somelongthingithaticantremember. 
What have I done wrong and/or what should I do to fix it?
Thanks for your time,
Yash.

Answer (score 0):

press ctrl+alt+t. in that terminal create that symbolic link.for that you should create a folder in /var/www

```
 cd /var/www
 mkdir yourfoldername
```

then create the symbolic link for it from that your wordpress folder

```
 sudo ln -s /home/path/to/yourfoldername/ /var/www/yourfoldername
```

after that, gives the file permission to that folder.

```
 chmod 777 -R /home/path/to/yourfoldername
```

then try it in your browser as you done before.(remember 777 gives the full permission)